# Why does Selenium Webdriver start failing tests if I focus off its FireFox window?

Tags: firefox, testing, selenium, webdriver, testng

I have some SeleniumWebdriver/TestNG tests that Im successfully running on FireFox. If I am watching the tests run, it is okay.
But If I start using another browser in the meanwhile, or skype for example, and I go back to the FireFox window that is running the tests, I always find out that some error has occurred - for example, the "User name" input hasnt been filled out.

Why does this happen, and how can I prevent it?

Comment: How are your running our tests? For me each individual test spawns a new firefox instance, that appears in the foreground (which can get very annoying) (edit, accidently added that as an answer)

Comment: Im running my tests in exactly the same way as you do.

Comment: What I mean is are you just launching from an eclipse project? I use ant to launch my tests for automated nightly testing. At one point I launched to a seperate tty on my machine(linux). This caused the tests to hang until I checked on them, at which point they would continue as expected. Its  possible that if the windows are popping up as you work you are accidently clicking away from the box the test is about to fill in through nothing more than bad luck/timing..

Comment: Well, I've tried launching them from an eclipse project and I've also tried launching them from the command line as Maven projects with "mvn-package" and both ways, every time I navigate off the firefox window, it fails the test by missing some field

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use `driver.switchTo().window(driver.getWindowHandle());` when filling out the form.

Comment: I get two red underlines when I try to use this code. SwitchTo() wants to turn into switchTo() (with a lowercase "s") and "CurrentWindowHandle cannot be resolved or is not a field", and when i use getWindowHandle instead, "Window" gets a red underline

Comment: sorry, i haven't any ide now, so it is the source of all mistakes. post update try, it now. should work

Comment: I pasted this code before all the forms and now I can work while tests are running :)